# Maximize: specify the range of a parameter

Tags: mathematical-optimization, constraint

I am trying to do symbolic maximization of a function, and would like to specify the range of a parameter of that function.

I am able to set constraints of the variable I am maximizing over, but am not sure how to set constraints/range for a variable I am not maximizing over.

Here I would like to specify that a is always positive. How can I do that? And can this be done globally?

```
Maximize[{x^0.5 - a*x, x > 0}, x]
```

Thanks!

EDIT

A slightly more complicated example, where I am stuck: if I want to specify the exponent symbolically, and want to put a constraint on it (say $0<b<1$?)

```
Maximize[{x^b - a*x, x > 0}, x]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By putting `x^0.5` in your code, Mathematica assumes that you want to use machine arithmetic, and so will not return a result (since `a` doesn't have a definite numerical value.)  If you use `x^(1/2)` or `Sqrt[x]` instead, Mathematica will try to solve the problem symbolically instead of numerically, and actually return a symbolic result.  This result can then be simplified using `Simplify` and the appropriate `Assumptions`:

```
Maximize[{x^(1/2) - a*x, {x > 0}}, x];
Simplify[%, Assumptions -> a > 0]

(* {1/(4 a), {x -> 1/(4 a^2)}} *)
```

Comment: `Simplify[%, a > 0]` also works.

Comment: great, thanks @MichaelSeifert!! I tried to use your method for a slightly more complicated case, but was quickly stuck. I edited the question, hope you would kindly accept tp extend your answer to that case? Or should I start a new question? Thanks so much!